# Для чего wrap в jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, devops, jenkins-pipeline

Для чего использовать [wrap](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#wrap-general-build-wrapper) в jenkins? Можно проще объяснить.

Comment: Wrap([$class: 'BuildUser'])   к примеру, в нем используются параметры кто запустил, ID. Для чего это если через env можно получить. И другие места есть где используется wrap, для вывода цветного текста к примеру, ну немного не понимаю для чего эта обёртка.

Comment: wrap: General Build Wrapper
This is a special step that allows to call build wrappers (also called "Environment Configuration" in freestyle or similar projects). Just select the wrapper to use from the dropdown list and configure it as needed. Everything inside the wrapper block is under its effect.

Note that only Pipeline-compatible wrappers will be shown in the list.

To use this step you need to specify a delegate class, e.g wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper']).

Comment: Не совсем понимаю суть(((